# How to call disparate APIs coming from a single View?

Tags: python, django, rest

Let's say I'm writing a Dashboard View, and on the Dashboard the user can do 3 things: update their name, change their avatar, and add a friend.

These are 3 different things that require different API logic for each one. Is it better practice to write 3 different APIs, all at different URIs, to do these functions? Or is it better to put them all at the Dashboard's POST function, with a field sent in to say which one we're working on?

I've tried both things and they both work, but I'm kind of self-taught and don't know what's the best practice.

Comment: [api design best pratice](https://swagger.io/resources/articles/best-practices-in-api-design/), keep common thing together, different thing seperate